# xarray to_netcdf not netCDF

Tags: netcdf, hdf

I'm using xarray for some wave model processing, and it works great.  As long as I don't try to read to_netcdf results externally.   Even with the example from http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/io.html, the resulting file can't be ncdump-ed.

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

ds = xr.Dataset({'foo': (('x', 'y'), np.random.rand(4, 5))},
             coords={'x': [10, 20, 30, 40],
                        'y': pd.date_range('2000-01-01', periods=5),
                        'z': ('x', list('abcd'))})

ds.to_netcdf('saved_on_disk.nc')
```

-

```
prompt> ncdump -h saved_on_disk.nc
ncdump: saved_on_disk.nc: NetCDF: Unknown file format
```

I'm on a Mac, with netCDF4 1.2.4, python 2.7, and   xarray 0.9.6

Comment: The code works fine on my linux system (`ncdump` gives the expected output), so I guess that something is wrong with either `xarray` or `NetCDF4`. How did you install them, and did you try re-installing them?

Comment: Thanks, Bart.  I just determined that the issue is ncdump and library collisions. the netCDF file is fine. So definitely not an xarray issue at all.